# Evaluate custom model attribute in more generic way

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, system.componentmodel

I have a data model like below. One of its properties has been decorated with custom attribut - "Mergable":

```
public class Example
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Mergable(false)]
    public int ExampleId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a definition of "Mergable":

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MergableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MergableAttribute()
    {
        Mergable = false;
    }

    public MergableAttribute(bool value)
    {
        Mergable = value;
    }

    public bool Mergable { get; set; } = false;
}
```

I use AttributeEvaluator class to evaluate the attribute:

```
public class AttributeEvaluator
{
    public bool Evaluate(object instance, string propertyName)
    {
        AttributeCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)[propertyName].Attributes;
        foreach (var a in attributes)
        {
            if (a.GetType() == typeof(MergableAttribute))
            {
                return ((MergableAttribute)a).Mergable;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can get the value of the attribute from forms like below:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool x = new AttributeEvaluator().Evaluate(new Example(), "ExampleId");
    }
```

I'm wondering how I can make it more generic. Perfect situation would be to have single class to evaluate all custom attributes. I can pass the attribute type to Evaluate method, but can't cast it to appropriate type to get "Mergable" value.

```
public class AttributeEvaluator
{
    public bool Evaluate(object instance, string propertyName, Type attributeType)
    {
        AttributeCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)[propertyName].Attributes;
        foreach (var a in attributes)
        {
            if (a.GetType() == attributeType)
            {
                return ((MergableAttribute)a).Mergable; //<-- how to cast a to appopriate type?
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve that or it's just wild-goose chase?

Comment: Use reflection to get the property value. `attributeType.GetProperty("Mergeable").GetValue(a)` or some such. You'll want to parameterize the name of the attribute property. Are you sure you only want to be able to get attribute properties that happen to be boolean?

Comment: why doe you have a bool on the attribute? why not just say if a property *has* the attribute on it, it's mergable, and if the attribute is not there, then it's not mergable. Then you can just check on the existence of the attribute

Comment: Thanks Ed. Can't believe it was so easy :) For now that boolean will be fine

Comment: @KMoussa, thanks, your suggestion is also a way to go. Maybe even better. I took [Browsable] attribute as example and coded it like this

Comment: How to use it for dataGridView in similar way [Browsable] is used? I mean, if column (property) is mergeable, merge cells of this column in the grid. I have the code for merging but it works on column number instead.